# why optimeDate is not changing while MongoDB secondary node is RECOVERING?

Tags: mongodb

I found that optimeDate is not changing while MongoDB secondary node is RECOVERING.

Does it mean that the RECOVERING doesn't have any progress?

Here is the output of rs.status(), the optimeDate of node03 is ISODate("2018-07-18T13:29:54Z") and it is never changing.

```
rs.status()
{
    "set" : "rs0",
    "date" : ISODate("2018-07-18T17:19:09.282Z"),
    "myState" : 1,
    "term" : NumberLong(112),
    "heartbeatIntervalMillis" : NumberLong(2000),
    "members" : [
        {
            "_id" : 3,
            "name" : "node04:27017",
            "health" : 1,
            "state" : 1,
            "stateStr" : "PRIMARY",
            "uptime" : 4492076,
            "optime" : {
                "ts" : Timestamp(1531934019, 1),
                "t" : NumberLong(112)
            },
            "optimeDate" : ISODate("2018-07-18T17:13:39Z"),
            "electionTime" : Timestamp(1531927161, 1),
            "electionDate" : ISODate("2018-07-18T15:19:21Z"),
            "configVersion" : 50813,
            "self" : true
        },
        {
            "_id" : 4,
            "name" : "node02:27017",
            "health" : 1,
            "state" : 7,
            "stateStr" : "ARBITER",
            "uptime" : 7181,
            "lastHeartbeat" : ISODate("2018-07-18T17:19:09.060Z"),
            "lastHeartbeatRecv" : ISODate("2018-07-18T17:19:08.707Z"),
            "pingMs" : NumberLong(0),
            "configVersion" : 50813
        },
        {
            "_id" : 5,
            "name" : "node03:27017",
            "health" : 1,
            "state" : 3,
            "stateStr" : "RECOVERING",
            "uptime" : 7192,
            "optime" : {
                "ts" : Timestamp(1531920594, 57),
                "t" : NumberLong(107)
            },
            "optimeDate" : ISODate("2018-07-18T13:29:54Z"),
            "lastHeartbeat" : ISODate("2018-07-18T17:19:08.769Z"),
            "lastHeartbeatRecv" : ISODate("2018-07-18T17:19:09.090Z"),
            "pingMs" : NumberLong(0),
            "configVersion" : 50813
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

Comment: I have a similar issue, let me know if figured out

Answer (score 1):

I checked the log of mongodb container. Actually, the RECOVERING if failed:

```
docker logs --tail 1000 composedeployment_mongo_1 | grep  REPL
2018-07-18T21:31:18.517+0000 I REPL     [ReplicationExecutor] syncing from: node04:27017
2018-07-18T21:31:18.519+0000 W REPL     [rsBackgroundSync] we are too stale to use node04:27017 as a sync source
2018-07-18T21:31:18.519+0000 I REPL     [ReplicationExecutor] could not find member to sync from
2018-07-18T21:31:18.519+0000 E REPL     [rsBackgroundSync] too stale to catch up -- entering maintenance mode
2018-07-18T21:31:18.519+0000 I REPL     [rsBackgroundSync] our last optime : (term: 107, timestamp: Jul 18 13:29:54:38)
2018-07-18T21:31:18.519+0000 I REPL     [rsBackgroundSync] oldest available is (term: 112, timestamp: Jul 18 16:36:08:87)
2018-07-18T21:31:18.519+0000 I REPL     [rsBackgroundSync] See http://dochub.mongodb.org/core/resyncingaverystalereplicasetmember
2018-07-18T21:31:18.519+0000 I REPL     [ReplicationExecutor] going into maintenance
```

I have to copy data from primary node to secondary node and restart mongodb secondary